# Exclude extensions of a class from Typescript union

Tags: typescript

How can I remove all types that extend a particular class from a union type in Typescript?

```js
class Failure {}
class ParseFailure extends Failure {}
class ExecutionFailure extends Failure {}

type Success = { ok: true }
type ExecutionResult = Success | ParseFailure | ExecutionFailure
type ExcludeFailures<T> = ???

// How can I define ExcludeFailures to have:
// ExcludeFailures<ExecutionResult> === Success
// ?
```

Comment: You classes are all empty [and don't play nicely with structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  Presumably your actual classes would be structurally distinct from `{}`, in which case you can just use `Exclude` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJXvlN).  Does that address your question fully? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I was unaware that empty classes play weirdly, but I also didn't know that a simple `Exclude<Something, Failure>` would have removed all extensions of `Failure` from the union. That's actually the answer I wanted! If you want to make it a proper answer instead of a comment I can accept it; otherwise, I'll make it on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to remove any elements of a union `T` that are assignable to the type `U`.  So as long as `Success` is not assignable to `Failure`, you can get the desired result like this:

```
type ExcludeFailures<T> = Exclude<T, Failure>

type Test = ExcludeFailures<ExecutionResult>
// type Test = Success
```

Of course, in your example code, `Success` *is* assignable to `Failure`, since `Failure` is an *empty class*.  So in that example, `ExcludeFailures<ExecutionResult>` becomes `never`, which is not what you want.

But presumably your actual `Failure` class and subclasses won't be completely empty, so you don't have to worry about [the weird things that happen with empty types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  If you give `Failure` some structure that differs from `Success`, then everything works:

```
class Failure { notOkay = true } // <-- need some structural difference
class ParseFailure extends Failure { }
class ExecutionFailure extends Failure { }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiYEsQFcBOBTaBvaA7A9gC4DyA1mAJ7QC80hqymAvtAPSvQA8AtN3uugAm0CPgC2mCPWTBCaMCGiCEAMxXoMuYOgBQoSDAAKYVBHTwkaTOgAehdLkEwLKDNmhM94KNACiN9GBkQgR8XBcraFt7R2dEV0wcTx0EXHtUFTBtaABlGW0fHHxSAC46BmYdQgoAB0x-QODQ3AAldAhkEEIaXPz2mAAfaGNTc3jIoYagkLCIjCra+ptQZEExywwITgAVAD4e-xW1nYAaOHGMXZ0Fuuht9u7aQ5Q1ufbOKaawto6uq-Y6Is7g8enlgAUINdrkA)